# Prove $0$ is a partial limit of $a_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Looking for guidance for the following question:
Let $a_n$ a sequence, such that $\left| {{a_{n + 1}} - {a_n}} \right| < \frac{1}{n}$ and $\{5,-5\}$ are partial limits of $a_n$.
Show that $0$ is also a partial limit.

I don't see how both conditions can live together. Obviously, the difference between the terms of $a_n$ are getting closer and closer, so how can this sequence have $\{5,-5\}$ as partial limits?

I'd be glad for clarification and guidance :)

Comment: What is a "partial limit" (is  a limit of a subsequence)?

Comment: The sequence may start off increasing, get close to $5$, then decrease, reaching some number  close to $-5$, then increase ...

Comment: Note that in the sequence's journey between $5$ and $-5$, it takes "small steps", so it gets close to $0$ too in each stage.

Comment: @JoseAntonio, Indeed.

Comment: Note even more that the sequence doesn't need to oszillate exactly between 5 and -5; a farther journey where these are just intermediate stations is also possible.

Comment: Partial limit = limit of subsequence. As far as  I am concerned,"partial limit" is a completely standard term.

Comment: OK so.. I think I understand it intuitively. Every time $a_n$ must be closer and closer to $0$, when it passes it from $-5$ to $5$ and vice-versa. I still don't know how to prove it mathematically.

Comment: Use the fact it "crosses" $0$ infinitely many times, and consecutive values are "close" to each other - terms before and after the "crossing" are close to each other, and so, close to 0 as well.

Comment: @Roland, what did you mean by "a farther journey where these are just intermediate stations is also possible"?

Comment: @AndrePoole $\{-5,5\}$ don't need to be the most extreme partial limits - it's possible that the sequence is not oscillating between -5 and 5, but between -10 and 10. All I wanted to stress s that one should not (need to) assume that the sequence only approaches $\pm 5$ and then returns back to the other value.

Comment: So in general, if there are two partial limits $a,b$, then every $c \in (a,b)$ is also a partial limit? (Considering the other information of this question).

Comment: Yes, that's right, as long as the "step size" tends to $0$.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I had never heard the term "partial limit" before; I think I like the term. The terminology I'm familiar with is "limit point".

Answer (score 3):

You need to show that the exists a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ converging to zero.

Equivalently, you need to show that, for every $N>0$ and $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $n>N$, such that
$$
|a_n|<\varepsilon.
$$
Let $N>0$ and $\varepsilon>0$. We shall find an $a_m$ absolutely smaller that $\varepsilon$, for $m>N$.

As there exists a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ converging to $5$, the exists
$$
n_1>\max\{\lfloor \varepsilon^{-1}\rfloor, N\},
$$
such that $a_{n_1}>0$, and as there exists a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ converging to $-5$, the exists 
$$
n_2>n_1,
$$
such that $a_{n_2}<0$.

So we have that $a_{n_2}<0<a_{n_1}$.

Let
$$
m=\min\{ n: n>n_1 \,\,\&\,\, a_n<0\}.
$$
This means that
$$
a_m<0\le a_{m-1},
$$
and at the same time
$$
|a_m-a_{m-1}|<\frac{1}{m-1}<\frac{1}{n_1}<\frac{1}{\lfloor \varepsilon^{-1}\rfloor}\le \varepsilon.
$$
Thus 
$$
|a_m|=-a_m\le a_{m-1}-a_m<\varepsilon.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The basic reason is that the harmonic series diverges. You can go an infinite distance by using only the steps $s_n := a_{n+1} - a_n$ such that $|s_n| = \frac{1}{n}$. (So, by telescoping series, we have then that $a_n = -a_1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} s_n$.)

By the way, I have never heard of the term "partial limit", but the definition given in the comment by DonAntonio sounds reasonable though: a partial limit of a sequence $\{a_n\}$ is a limit of a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$. (I would have described this as a limit point of the set of points which comprise the sequence.)

Answer (score 0):

David Mitra's suggestion makes sense..

Like start with $a_0 =$ -5, $a_1 =$ -5 + 1, $a_2 =$ -5 + $\frac{1}{2}$, $\dots$ till $a_{n_1} > 5$ now we start subtracting i.e. $a_{n_1+1} = a_{n_1} - \frac{1}{n_1+1}$, $\dots$ till a_{n_2} < -5 then we again start adding i.e. $a_{n_2 + 1} = a_{n_2} + \frac{1}{n_2 + 1}$ till it is greater than 5 again, and so on and so forth.

We are always sure to reach -5 and 5 i.e cross out of $[-5,5]$, because harmonic series as Kelly points outs diverges, $\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow \infty$.

And the two (particular) limits (partial limits in your case) of this kind of sequence will be -5 and 5, as our step size goes to $0$, so everytime we cross 5 or -5 say at $a_{n_1}$ and $a_{n_2}$ we know for sure that $a_{n_1} \leq 5 + \frac{1}{n_1}$ and similarly 
$ a_{n_2} \geq -5 - \frac{1}{n_2} $ where the subsequence of $ n_1 < n_2 < \dots $.

Probably this would be the kind of sequence you are interested in. But I have a question regarding this answer. See comments below. :)

---

Consider any point in x∈[−5,5]. So when oscillating between -5 and 5, you cross this x every time and each time with a smaller step. And consider the subsequence where you go from one side of x to other side, this subsequence converges to x again for the same reason why −5 and 5 are limits, i.e smaller step size each time. :)

Comment: I think the whole interval $[-5,5]$ is the collection of limits for this sequence, where $0 \in [-5,5]$.

Comment: The only sequence for example I can think of here which have exactly 3 limits $\{ -5, 5, 0 \}$ is mixing three constant sequences for e.g. $-5, 0, 5, -5, 0, 5, \dots$

Comment: Please comment on the answer and comments.

Comment: Consider any point in $x  \in [-5,5]$. So when oscillating between -5 and 5, you cross this $x$ every time and each time with a smaller step. And consider the subsequence where you go from one side of $x$ to other side, this subsequence converges to $x$ again for the same reason why $-5$ and $5$ are limits, i.e smaller step size each time. :)