# Proving 0 is partial limit of $ (a_n) $ [ non-constructive proof ]

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

**Problem**: If sequence $(a_n)$ has $10$,$-10$ as partial limits and in addition $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}.|a_{n+1} − a_{n} |≤ \frac{1}{n} $, then 0 is a partial limit of $ (a_n) $.

**Note**: There exists a proof which is constructive ( that is what I asked here [Proving $0$ is partial limit of $ a_n $ - Why such an $ n $ exists s.t. it satisfies $ a_n \leq 0 $ , $ a_{n+1} >0 $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4113879/proving-0-is-partial-limit-of-a-n-why-such-an-n-exists-s-t-it-satis) ) , but there exists another proof that is non-constructive which assumes $ (a_n)  $ does not converge to $ 0 $ and we reach a contradiction , this is what I'll show next.

**Proof :**
Suppose that $ 0 $ isn't a partial limit of $ (a_n) $. Then there exists $ \epsilon_0 > 0 $ and $ N \in \mathbb{N} $ s.t.  $ \forall n \geq N. | a_n - 0  | \geq \epsilon_0  $ ( the defintion for a partial limit $ L $ of some sequence sequence $ (b_n) $ is $ \forall \epsilon>0. \forall N \in \mathbb{N} .\exists n \geq N. | b_n - L | \leq \epsilon  $, so we just used the negation of it in our proof ).
Hence $ \forall n \geq N. a_n \leq -\epsilon_0 \lor a_n \geq \epsilon_0  $. There exists $ N^* \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $ N^* \geq max \{ N,\frac{1}{2\epsilon_0} \} $.
Instantiatng $ N^* $ we get that $ a_{N^*} \leq -\epsilon_0 \lor a_{N^*} \geq \epsilon_0  $. Suppose without lose of generality that $ a_{N^*} \leq -\epsilon_0 $. We define the set $ A = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : n>N^* , a_n \geq \epsilon_0 \} $, $\color{red}{ \text{since $ +10 $ is a partial limit of $ (a_n) $ then $A \neq \emptyset$} } $    , Hence $ A $ has a minimum ( since $ A $ is a set of naturals, it has minimum [ we use well-ordering principle here ] ) which we designate as $ M = min A $.
Hence $ a_M \geq \epsilon_0 $ and $ a_{M-1} \leq -\epsilon_0 $, Hence $ a_M - a_{M-1} \geq 2 \epsilon_0 > \frac{1}{N^*} \geq \frac{1}{M-1} $ ( note: since we have  $ M > N^* $ then $ M -1 \geq N^* $ hence $ \frac{1}{N^*} \geq \frac{1}{M -1} $  ), so $ |a_M - a_{M-1} | \geq 2 \epsilon_0 > \frac{1}{N^*} \geq \frac{1}{M-1} $. But after instantiation  ( of $ M-1 $ in $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}.|a_{n+1} − a_{n} |≤ \frac{1}{n} $ ) we get $ |a_M - a_{M-1} | \leq \frac{1}{M-1} $ which is a contradiction.

**My question:** I didn't fully understand why the set $ A = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : n>N^* , a_n \geq \epsilon_0 \} $ is non-empty, how does the fact that $ +10  $ is a partial limit help me understand this? ( since $+10 $ is a partial limit we have $ \forall \epsilon>0. \forall N \in \mathbb{N} .\exists n \geq N. | a_n - 10 | \leq \epsilon $ , but I have no idea how instantiating here with $ \epsilon_0 $ or $ N^* $ helps me)

Comment: Use $$ a_n = 10 - (10-a_n)\geq 10 -\vert 10-a_n\vert \geq 10-\varepsilon >\varepsilon_0.$$

Comment: Hmm, what $ \epsilon $ should be though?, It must be guaranteed that $ 10 - \epsilon > \epsilon_0 $ but I'm not quite seeing what $ \epsilon $ would guarantee it.

Comment: Well, we pick $\varepsilon_0$ in the beginning and wlog we can pick it smaller than $1$. Then pick $\varepsilon =1$ and you are done.

Comment: On an intuitiv level this is easy to see. As $10$ is a partial limit, there exists a subsequence converging to it and in particular for arbitrary large indices, there exists a possibly larger $M$ such that $a_M$ is as close to $10$ as we like. In particular $a_M>\varepsilon_0$ which is small.

Comment: Since we assumed wlog that $ \forall n>N.  a_n  \leq - \epsilon_0 $, then $ -a_n \geq \epsilon_0  \iff 
\epsilon > |10- a_n| \geq 10 -a_n \geq  10 +\epsilon_0 $.
It seems to me if we will choose $ \epsilon = \epsilon_0 $ we'll get a contradiction ( we'd have $ \epsilon_0 \geq 10 + \epsilon_0 $ ). Where my error lies?

Comment: Where did you get the inequality for $\varepsilon$ from?

Comment: Also where did we assume $a_n\leq -\varepsilon_0$? You seem to be missing some absolute value

Comment: Yeah you are right, I did a mistake. I only assumed  wlog $ a_{N^*} \leq -\epsilon_0 $ in the proof.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven So I see why the case If $ \epsilon_0 < 1$ would be true. But what would I do if $ \epsilon_0 \geq 1 $? I don't quite see how to proceed from this case.

Comment: You are the one choosing $\varepsilon_0$ and the only condition it needs to satisfy is that it is smaller than the $\vert a_n \vert$, so you can just choose it even smaller and make it less than $1$.

Comment: But I just know that $ \epsilon_0 $  exists. I don't know if it is smaller or bigger than $ 1 $. Maybe the proof above should be restructured so that it'll work even for very large or very small $ \epsilon_0 $?

Comment: Please reread carefully, what I wrote above. If you pick $\varepsilon_0$ as you did, then you can choose $\hat{\varepsilon_0}:=\min\{ 1, \varepsilon_0 \}$, then clearly this quantity is still smaller than $\vert a_n \vert$ and it is smaller or equal than $1$. So wlog we can assume that $\varepsilon_0\leq1$.

Comment: And then I could reformulate the proof for $ \hat{ \varepsilon_0 }  $  and so I could  define the set as  $ A = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : n>N^* , a_n \geq \hat{\varepsilon_0} \} $ instead of just  with $ \epsilon_0 $. And then it will surely be satisfied that $ a_n = 10 - (10-a_n)\geq 10 -\vert 10-a_n\vert \geq 10-\varepsilon >  \hat{ \varepsilon_0 }   $ , for $ \epsilon = 1 $. That'll work?

Comment: Or you can just say, wlog $\varepsilon_0\leq 1$ by the argument I gave above. Your notation is already way to complicated. Anyway, I think you can handle it from here, I suggest that you try to write up an answer, that will clear things up in your head and the community can give you feedback on your proof writing.